# I need powershell command get the protocol type of azure netapp files volume

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to create a powershell script where ot can pull the data of azure netapp file volume protocol type

```
Get-Aznetappfilevolume
```

Comment: kindly share the commands, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a powershell script where ot can pull the data of azure netapp file volume protocol type.

Here is the **Powershell** code to find out the `netapp files protocol type`.

> I have followed [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.netappfiles/get-aznetappfilesvolume?view=azps-9.7.1) as a reference to to check the NetAppFiles Protocol type.

```
 Install-Module Az.NetAppFiles  -AllowClobber -Force 
 Import-Module Az.NetAppFiles -Force 
 $netapp = Get-AzNetAppFilesVolume -ResourceGroupName "v-venkat-mindtree" -AccountName "venkatnetapp" -PoolName "sample" -Name "volume1"
 $netapp.ProtocolTypes
```

Output:

[image]